# How to log2 transform axes of my graph ploted by the package plotly in R?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Currently I am using plotly in R, 
and I wonder what code should I use to log2 transform one of the axes ?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to do `log` transform on the x-axis. However, I don't know if it is possible to do `log2`.

```
library(plotly)

mtcars %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~disp, y = ~mpg) %>%
  add_markers(marker = list(opacity = 0.8)) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(type = "log"))
```

An alternative is to use `ggplot2` with `scale_x_continuous` with `trans = "log2"`, and then `ggplotly`

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2")

ggplotly(p)
```